# WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity( rails 2 to rails 3)

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

After upgrading rails application from `rails 2.3.14` to `rails 3.2.6`, i am getting following error in most `ajax post requests`.

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

i tried a solution .. .

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);   
});
```

but it is not working.

any idea to overcome this error??

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the

```
jquery-rails
```

gem , it automatically sets the csrf token for all ajax requests..